# @keyframes não funciona

Tags: css, css3

tenho uma função **jQuery** que adiciona a uma **div** a classe abaixo:

```
.brancoTransparente {
  animation: cor;
  opacity: .9;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.brancoTransparente a {
  color: #000;
}
@keyframes cor{
  0% {
    background-color: transparente;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

a cor do link está trocando de boa, o que leva a crer que o **jQuery** está inserindo a classe. Mas a cor de fundo não está trocando.

O que fiz de errado?

**Obs.:** fazendo como abaixo funciona. No entanto, o novo **background** aparece abruptamente e eu gostaria que aparece como efeito **fadein**:

```
.brancoTransparente {
    opacity: .9;
    background: #fff;
}
.brancoTransparente a {
    color: #000;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

É uma corrida no **scrool** do navegador abaixo de **5px** troca de cor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que a `class` mantenha as propriedades da animação basta adicionar a propriedade `animation-fill-mode` e escolher o valor necessário.

> **Valores**
>   **none**
>   A animação não aplicará nenhum estilo ao destino quando ele não estiver sendo executado; Em vez disso, ele será exibido usando seu estado com base em todas as outras regras CSS aplicadas a ele.
>   **forwards**
>   O destino reterá os valores computados definidos pelo último quadro-chave encontrado durante a execução.
>   **backwards**
>   A animação aplicará os valores definidos no primeiro quadro-chave relevante assim que ele for aplicado ao destino e reterá isso durante o `animation-delay` período.
>   **both**
>   A animação seguirá as regras para frente e para trás, estendendo as propriedades da animação em ambas as direções.

Recomendo você a utilizar `animation-fill-mode: both`, assim a classe irá manter as propriedades definidas na animação.

```css
.brancoTransparente {
  opacity: .9;
  transition: all .3s;
  animation: cor;
  background-color: blue;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.brancoTransparente a {
  color: #000;
}
@keyframes cor{
  0% {
    background-color: transparente;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="brancoTransparente">
    <a>Teste</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade funciona, só que ele volta ao estado inicial dele, não fica no estado da animação.

Coloque um animation duration de algum tempo e observe que a animação vai funcionar:

```css
.brancoTransparente {
  opacity: .9;
  transition: all .3s;
  animation: cor;
  background-color: blue;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.brancoTransparente a {
  color: #000;
}
@keyframes cor{
  0% {
    background-color: transparente;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="brancoTransparente">
    <a>Teste</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Note: The animation-duration property defines how long time an
>   animation should take to complete. If the animation-duration property
>   is not specified, no animation will occur, because the default value
>   is 0s (0 seconds).
>
> ---
>
> Nota: A propriedade animation-duration define quanto tempo uma
>   animação deve demorar para ser concluída. Se a animation-duration não
>   for especificada, nenhuma animação ocorrerá, porque o valor padrão é
>   0s (0 segundos).
>   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: entendi! Mas eu preciso que essa cor apos alterada, não mude mais até que o volte aos 5px do topo da pagina. Ou seja, mudar gradativo até chegar nos 100% da aimação e apos isso, ter uma opacidade .9 e ficar durante toda a pagina

Comment: Adicionei informações à pergunta!